# HTML form Validation With PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, authentication

I tried a simple html form for logging in but the form doesn't respond.
I am new to PHP programming.

Please help

```
<?php
$match = 'honey';

if (isset($user_name) && isset($password)) {
    $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $submit = $_POST['submit'];

    if (!empty($user_name) && !empty($password)) {
        if ($password == $match) {
            echo 'Logged in';
        } else
            echo 'Incorrect password or username';
    } else
        echo 'Please fill in all the fields';


}

?>

<form action="index.php" method="POST">
Username:<input type="text" name="user_name" /><br><br>
Password:<input type ="password" name="password"/><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

Comment: [Your conditionals are trying to match variables, where they should be the POST arrays themselves. Error reporting would have signaled undefined variables.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are using `isset()` for variables you haven't declared yet.

Change your

```
if (isset($user_name) && isset($password))
```

To

```
if (isset($_POST['user_name']) && isset($_POST['password'])
```

Answer (score 1):

`username` and `password` were not defined

it should be

```
if(isset($_POST['user_name') && isset($_POST['password'])){

 $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$submit = $_POST['submit'];

if (!empty($user_name) && !empty($password)) {
    if ($password == $match) {
        echo 'Logged in';
    } else
        echo 'Incorrect password or username';
} else
    echo 'Please fill in all the fields';

}
```